# What to call the exponent of 10 in scientific numbers?

Tags: terminology

I'm writing a software API for tracking measurements, and the API has an option for configuring the precision of the values displayed. The configuration is a number that serves as the exponent of a power-of-10 multiplier (i.e. scientific notation); e.g. if the measurement units are `meters`, if this number that configures the precision is `-3`, the multiplier is `0.001` and the displayed units are `millimeters`. Or if the configured precision is `3`, the multiplier is `1000` and the displayed units are `kilometers`.

What simple, succinct, & specific mathematical word can I use as the name of this configuration value? I.e., what can I call '`n`' in this: **Measurement x 10<sup>n</sup>**

The term "multiplier" isn't accurate since by itself that number isn't a multiplier, and "scaler" doesn't seem right either.

Comment: The appropriate mathematical term to use is that $n$ is an "exponent" of 10

Comment: A google-books search for ["scientific notation" + mantissa](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22scientific+notation%22+mantissa) ("mantissa", because that's what the value in front of $10^n$ is usually called) indicates that "exponent" is typically used.

Answer (score 2):

In scientific notation, such as $9.81 \times 10^4$, we call $9.81$ the **mantissa** and $4$ the **exponent**.

Comment: But `4` seems like an exponent of `10`, not an exponent of `9.81`. Is there another word that makes it clear that the `4` is a power of `10` that is then used as a multiplier of `9.81`?

Comment: Maybe you could say that $10$ is the *base* then?